# Extra argument 'method' in call in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, alamofire, xcode8, ios10

I'm getting this error : `Extra arguement in 'method' in call`. I am using  XCode 8, Swift 3.0 and iOS 10.0.

I'm attaching the screenshots for the code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is because of migration from swift 2.0 to 3.0, here your exiting method is depreciated please check inside alamofire framework you will get new request method.

Comment: @Bucket I have already updated my pods

Comment: Yes, but i think this is implemented in your view controller, correct ?

Comment: Implemented means? I have import statement

Comment: Try to rewrite Alamofire.request. here you will get same method name with less parameters .

Comment: But I need to pass Parameters and Headers, both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128261/discussion-between-bucket-and-vaibhav-jhaveri).

Answer (score 2):

try once below code

```
 Alamofire.request("Your URL", method: .post, parameters:   parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
    case .success(_):

        break

    case .failure(_):

        break

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change in your code

```
encoding:URLEncoding.httpBody
```

to

```
encoding:URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)
```

Try this in your code for New **Alamofire 4.0**

### Swift 3

```
 Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        self.successGetData(response.result.value! as AnyObject)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
```

Source : - [Alamofire 4.0](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: You but this is working code for iOS 10 and also provided the Latest git code of the Alamofire 4.0 for Swift 3, i also used same thing inside my code tested then i gave my answer here. @Vaibhav Jhaveri

Comment: I know you tested, but its not working in my case. So the issue might be something else @Anand

Comment: What thing is not working? Is this code showing any error inside your code?

Comment: If you can look at the first screenshot, the error is pointing at `method: .post`

Comment: Yes i saw then i give you solution and this code should be work inside your code.Please show me your code in your question.